# How to find other people to improve English speaking ability?

Tags: english, speaking

I'm an intermediate student of English. I would like to improve my speaking skills. How can I join an online group to speak with other students?

Answer (score 2):

There are many sites that allow you to find English language speaking partners, though not necessarily groups.

- The FluentU blog post [Want to Practice Speaking English with a Native Speaker? Go Online!](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/english/english-speaking-online/) (published in March 2016 and updated in June 2020) discusses several options, some of which are free (e.g. [Conversation Exchange](https://conversationexchange.com/), [Go Speaky](https://www.gospeaky.net/), [Busuu](https://www.busuu.com/en) and [Lingoglobe](http://www.lingoglobe.com/)).
- [Find your English speaking partner online](https://ieltsgame.com/find-english-speaking-partner/) on IELTSGame.com, which recommends [italki](https://www.italki.com/partners).
- [Lingvonet](https://www.lingvonet.com/) allow you to find a speaking partner by country; you can also specify whether you want to use Skype or not.
- The article [How to Find Conversation Partners: The Best Language Exchange Sites](https://www.mosalingua.com/en/how-to-find-conversation-partners-best-language-exchange-sites/) on Mosalingua.com (originally published in 2013) discusses the pros and cons of various sites, including italki and Conversation Exchange.

Comment: I checked all of them already but, i couldn't speak to anyone  yet.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some speech or communication classes available in a local college. Right now all the classes are conducted virtually so they should have Zoom meetings where you can practice speaking.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any classes that available to anyone.